# Possible to initialize Laravel IoC with data?

Tags: php, oop, laravel

Trying to use the IoC as a factory. Can I pass data to initialize/construct object with?

```
App::bind('Song', function(){
    return new Song;
});
```

and mimic this (can $data never gets passed along, why?)

```
App::bind('Song', function($data=null){
    return new Song($data);
});
```

while the Class is

```
class Song extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = array(
        'id',
        'name',
        'type'
    );
}
```

The `App::make('Song',array('id'=>1,'name'=>'foo'))` call skips inserting my arguments inside Illuminate\Container - the initialized class does not contain any defined attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data to an anonymous function using 'use':

```
App::bind('Song', function() use ($data) {
    return new Song($data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the Song object binding. `$dynamicData` can be any concrete object, array or primitive type.

```
App::bind('Song', function($app, $dynamicData){
    return new Song($dynamicData);
});
```

Pass the dynamic data to the concrete object

```
$song = App::make('Song', ['name' => 'foo', 'type' => 'bar']);
```